# Get constructor by name in JS with Webpack and Babel

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, vue-cli

I'm currently working on a projet using Webpack and Babel. More specifically I use the vue-cli framework, but that shouldn't matter.

I'd like to fetch a constructor from it's string name.

My class is set like that in a World.ts file :

```
export default class World { ... }
```

And used like this in another file :

```
import World from "./World";
```

What I'd like to do is :

```
let foo = new World();
let className = foo.constructor.name;
let bar = new SCOPE[className]();
```

The issue is that I don't find the right SCOPE.
I've tried `window[className]` it doesn't work.
I've tried `eval('let bar = new ${className}()')`, doesn't work either.
I've tried `const SCOPE = (0, eval)("this")` beneath my imports with no more success, it returns the `window` object.

So far the only solution I found is to create a Map of my constructors by their name, but that is not dynamic at all.

```
const classesByName = new Map<string, any>([
  [World.name, World],
  ...
]);
```

So... I guess Webpack or Babel is doing something somewhere.
How could I do ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: Dynamicaly unparsing JSON objects under a specific prototype.

Comment: That sentence does not make sense. What does "unparsing" mean?

Comment: "parsing" my bad.
Yeah, I know what JSON is, I was synthesizing... What I want is to start with a JSON string and end up with an Object of a sepcific Class. The whole dynamically, using a `type` property, Object.assign and stuff.

Comment: @FlorentDescroix Ah, that makes much more sense. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue is that I don't find the right SCOPE.

There isn't one, given your description. Although the JavaScript engine will have a record of each import in your module, that list of records is not accessible to your code.

If you want to do this, you'll need to put the objects/constructors you want to do it with in an object or `Map` yourself, and then use them from there.

**If** you had those various constructors as named exports in a module, like this:

```
export class World { /* ... */ }
export class Universe { /* ... */ }
export class Multiverse { /* ... */ }
```

...then you could use the module namespace object for the module, like this:

```
import * as constructors from "./your-module.js";

const name = /*...get the name of one of the constructors dynamically...*/;
const newInstance = new constructors[name]();
```

But of course, many constructors expect to receive arguments.

---

**But**, you've said:

> What I'd like to do is :
>
> ```
> let foo = new World();
> let className = foo.constructor.name;
> let bar = new SCOPE[className]();
> ```

There's no reason to go through the name like that if you have an instance of the class, just use `foo.constructor`:

```js
class World {
}


let foo = new World();
let bar = new foo.constructor();
console.log(bar instanceof World); // true
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Is there any way to have my Class definitions accessible anywhere then (the way it would be without export) ? At least it would be quite useful for the debug in the console.

On thing that comes to mind is you could have a class registry and have your modules that export classes use the registry. For instance:

`registry.js`:

```
const registry = new Map();
export function registerClass(cls) {
    registry.set(cls.name, cls);
    return cls;
}
export function getClass(name) {
    return registry.get(name);
}
```

Then in `World.js`:

```
import { registerClass } from "./registry.js";
export default registerClass(class World {
    // ...
});
```

Or if using a named export:

```
import { registerClass } from "./registry.js";
export class World {
    // ...
}
registerClass(World);
```

When you want to use one from the name:

```
import { getClass } from "./registry.js";
const Ctor = getClass(name);
const obj = new Ctor();
```

Comment: I was actually synthesising my code to give the idea of what I'm looking for.  
Obviously, if it was that simple I would have any issues ^^

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about the exports, I better understand now.  
Is there any way to have my Class definitions accessible anywhere then (the way it would be without export) ? At least it would be quite useful for the debug in the console.

Comment: @FlorentDescroix - You could maintain a registry. I've added to the answer. Happy coding!